# Approximate known non-linear function using linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, linear, approximation

Consider the following model:

$$
y_{i}=f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i};\theta\right)+\varepsilon_{i}
$$

where $y_{i}$ is the dependent variable, $\boldsymbol{x}_{i}$ is
a vector of explanatory variables, $\varepsilon_{i}$ is $iid\left(0,\sigma^{2}\right)$
noise (here presented as additive noise, but it could be more general)
and $\theta$ is a vector of unknown parameters.

$f$ is a known continuous differentiable function.The obvious choice
would be to use non-linear regression to estimate the unknown parameters $\theta$. But lets say I insist on using
linear regression which have an analytical solution. What choices do I have? I am not interested in
doing inference on the parameters $\theta$. I am more interested
in an approximation:

$$f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i};\theta\right)\approx g\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i}\right)\beta
$$

linear in the parameters $\beta$.

One could specify $g$ as being polynomials of $\boldsymbol{x}_{i}$,
to approximate a broad range of functions. However, this approach
will not make use of any information about the known function $f$.
For other functional forms e.g. $f\left(x\right)=e^{x\theta}$ one
may use a transformation of the $y$-variable, but this is not what
I am looking for either.

Comment: Do you have a specific $f$ or class of $f$ in mind?  Note that transforming the $y$ variable produces a different model because the random variables $\varepsilon_i$ are no longer added to $f.$  One routine solution to to use splines, not polynomials.

Comment: No specific function or class, except continuous differentiable functions. I was hoping one could do something inspired by a Taylor approximation that uses information about the derivatives of $f$, but is linear in parameters so that OLS can be used.